# How to determine lexicographically the smallest Prüfer-Code of a spanning tree?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

First, *lexicographically the smallest* means e.g. 112 < 121 and 121 < 211.

**EDIT:**
Then how to determine the minimal Prüfer-Code of a spanning tree from the given graph:

[image: Graph]

Should I first find the minimal spanning tree?

Any suggestions?

Comment: It was my understanding that the prufer code could only be applied to labeled trees.  could you post a link or provide an explanation of how to do this with graphs that are not trees??

Comment: Well, sorry it is my fault I have poorly understood the question. An edit is coming.

Comment: In tjis form I get: 013546 of the spanning tree with the same nodes and edges between $e_1$ = {0,2}, $e_2$ = {0,1}, $e_3$ = {1,3}, $e_4$ = {3,5}, $e_5$ = {5,4}, $e_6$ = {4,6}, $e_7$ = {6,7}. Correct?

Comment: So basically we're looking for a spanning tree of this graph that will give a prufer code that is minimum (lexicographically)?

Comment: @PaddlingGhost yes.

Comment: I've already found one less than that code.  I'm not sure it's going to be the minimum, but its better.  basically let the spanning tree be the path $P: 6,0,1,2,3,5,4,7$.  This should give a prufer code of $s: 012354$.  I'll leave an aswer once i'm sure i've found a minimum.

Comment: @PaddlingGhost I have found now : $s : 006546$ for the $e_1$ = {0,1}, $e_2$ = {0,2}, $e_3$ = {0,6}, $e_4$ = {3,5}, $e_5$ = {5,4}, $e_6$ = {4,6}, $e_7$ = {6,7}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, we want as many $0$s in the beginning of our prufer code as we can.  We can get at most 2.  Thus, the minimum prufer will occur when there are exactly $ 2$ 0s in the beginning slots of the code.  After this, there are only 3 possible ways to construct the spanning tree from this point, so it is easy to try them all and determine the minimum.  Take the edges $e_1 = (0,1);e_2 = (0,2); e_3= (0,6);e_4=(6,7);e_5=(4,6);e_6=(4,5);e_7 = (3,5).$  This yields the prufer code, $s: 006546$.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation!